# Order of C-O bond length

Tags: bond

> Find the correct order of increasing $\ce{C-O}$ bond length in $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{CO3^2-}$.

My solution: as bond length is inversely proportional to the bond order, the order would be $\ce{CO} < \ce{CO2} < \ce{CO3^2-}$. Am I correct?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80421/how-to-rationalise-the-increasing-bond-length-order-in-the-carbonate-ion-carbon/80422#80422 Same test, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Order]

The order is correct but this is my procedure.
Stronger the bond smaller the length